# Matlab Installation Issue for ubuntu14.04 with 32bits os

Tags: matlab

I have tried number of times to install MATLAB from Ubuntu software center but it didn't get install and it didn't even display any error message. It just keep on showing that it is being install and it make my system slow. I have Ubuntu 14.04 [32bits], through Mathworks site there is no option for 32bit Linux OS. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB installation offered by Software Center does not actually install MATLAB, instead it installs a `matlab-support` package:

> This package does not provide MATLAB. Instead, it configures an
>    existing MATLAB installation to integrate more comfortably in
>    a Debian installation.

Furthermore, as you have already deduced, Mathworks no longer support 32-bit Linux platforms: see the list of [System Requirements and Supported Compilers Archive](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html), according to which the last release to support 32-bit Linux platforms was [2012a](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/release2012b/linux.html)

> Note: Release 2012a was the last release of the 32-bit version of MATLAB for Linux. See the platform road map for more information.